# How do I list optional intermediary nodes between my two endpoint nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So, I have Countries, States, and Towns in my graph. There are two possible relationships between the country and town:

```
(c:Country)<-[:GEO_IN]-(s:State)<-[:GEO_IN]-(t:Town)
```

and

```
(c:Country)<-[:GEO_IN]-(t:Town)
```

I'm trying to generate a table that lists all the countries and states with a count of the towns. I think it makes sense to use a wild-card match for the relationship ...

```
Match(t:Town)-[:GEO_IN*]->(c:Country)
```

But now I'm not sure how to get the list of states out of that list. I'm using this very simple example to test and develop more sophisticated understanding. So I know I could do a couple of optional matches and then list them out, but what if I had n possible nodes between t and c?

The solution is much appreciated, but as you might guess, what I'd really like is more insight into how to think about cypher and which tools to employ and when.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your DB, do all `State` nodes have at least one related `Town`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use path aliases when you have a variable length, they're much easier.

```
MATCH path = (:Town) - [:GEO_IN*1..2] -> (:Country)
WITH NODES(path)[0] AS town, TAIL(NODES(path)) AS t_and_c
UNWIND t_and_c AS region
RETURN DISTINCT region, COUNT(DISTINCT town)
```

Check out the depths of the [refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/), there's a lot more to Cypher than just matching nodes.